# Matching info from 2 arrays, adding class if match

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a some elements that exist in a ul and would like to compare them to the current URL location, and add a class (active) to a specific li if there is a match. I think I have all the parts, but I can't seem to get them to all work. together. I am getting all elements in the current path, getting all elements in the nav structure (but not using this just yet as I am not sure how). Right now I am using a switch to add it to li:child(n), but that seems pretty strict. Is there a more efficient way to achieve what I am looking to do?

```
<ul class="nav-items">
   <li><a href="/About">About</a></li>
   <li class="active"><a href="/News">News</a></li>
   <li><a href="/Programs">Programs</a></li>
   <li><a href="/Public-Policy">Public Policy</a></li>
   <li><a href="/Events">Events</a></li>
   <li><a href="/Benefits">Benefits</a></li>
   <li><a href="/Education">Education</a></li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
  var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split( '/' );
  var navArray = $('.nav-items li a').map(function(i, el) {
    return $(el).text();}).get();//<--not sure how to use this just yet

  switch(pathArray[1]) {
    case "About":
        $('.nav-items li:nth-child(1)').addClass('active');
      break;
      case "News":
        $('.nav-items li:nth-child(2)').addClass('active');
      break;
      case "Programs":
        $('.nav-items li:nth-child(3)').addClass('active');
      break;
      case "Public-Policy":
        $('.nav-items li:nth-child(4)').addClass('active');
      break;
      case "Events":
        $('.nav-items li:nth-child(5)').addClass('active');
      break;
      case "Benefits":
        $('.nav-items li:nth-child(6)').addClass('active');
      break;
      case "Education":
        $('.nav-items li:nth-child(7)').addClass('active');
      break;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use jQuery's `.eq()` method, as it's zero-based. That can then be fed the index in the array of your pathname (which is also zero-based).

Note that this won't work with the `Public Policy` item, as the URL will be `Public-Policy`, and won't match. You might want to try comparing the URL instead.

```js
var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split('/');
pathArray = 'example.com/About'.split('/'); // because snippets don't have your URL
var navArray = $('.nav-items li a').map(function(i, el) {
  return $(el).text();
}).get();

$('.nav-items li').eq(navArray.indexOf(pathArray[1])).addClass('active');
```

```css
.active {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav-items">
   <li><a href="/About">About</a></li>
   <li><a href="/News">News</a></li>
   <li><a href="/Programs">Programs</a></li>
   <li><a href="/Public-Policy">Public Policy</a></li>
   <li><a href="/Events">Events</a></li>
   <li><a href="/Benefits">Benefits</a></li>
   <li><a href="/Education">Education</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Perfect! The system I am working in is going to consistently add dashes for canonical URLS, so I just added a little regex bit to the end to end up with: var navArray = $('.nav-items li a').map(function(i, el) {
  return $(el).text().replace(/\s+/g, "-");
}).get();       Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure if this is what you're looking for, but see this:

```
<ul class="nav-items">
    <li class="about-link"><a href="/About">About</a></li>
    <li class="news-link"><a href="/News">News</a></li>
    <li class="programs-link"><a href="/Programs">Programs</a></li>
    <li class="public-policy-link"><a href="/Public-Policy">Public Policy</a></li>
    <li class="events-link"><a href="/Events">Events</a></li>
    <li class="beenfits-link"><a href="/Benefits">Benefits</a></li>
    <li class="education-link"><a href="/Education">Education</a></li>
</ul>
```

And JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split( '/' );

    $('li.active').removeClass('active');
    $('.nav-items .' + pathArray[1].toLowerCase() + "-link").addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Its unnecessary to search the url in this case . The following code will accomplish your task with ease .

```
var nav = $('.nav-items li a');
nav.on('click', function() {
  nav.removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
})
```

This will add class to current anchor being clicked and simply remove class active from any others .

Comment: I feel like this would work if a page load didn't occur after the click. The workflow would be User click -> add active class -> new page loads -> nothing is active on new page...right?